# KDE Widget showing CPU cores

Tags: cpu, widgets

My latptop has a corei7 CPU. But I know it has only 4 cores. Why kde CPU Load Monitor widget shows 7 cpu cores?

[image]

Also Gnome system monitor shows 8 CPUs:

[image]

Comment: The CPU Load Monitor widget does show 8 cores, from cpu0 to cpu7. You see 8 logical cores because of hyperthreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CPU uses hyper-threading to run 2 threads per physical core.
These are faster than your typical thread, so you effectively have 8 cores.
We call these logical cores.

Comment: @Nmath I can still see the comment by edwinksl